# Can I make a docked playlist in vlc NOT dominate the window?

Tags: vlc

I'd like to be able to view my playlist in vlc in a manner where it is non-obtrusive. Currently it looks something like this:

My desire is kind of the opposite - have the actual video playing take up the majority of the screen and have the playlist unobtrusively off to the side (actually in reality I would probably be happy with an undocked playlist except for [this bug](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/12084).

[image]

I'm aware there is a hidden resizer between the video and the media sources thing, but in the image shown I cannot resize the video portion any larger than that.

Comment: I'd also like to know. This is nuts..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I know this is a late response, but if anyone else is looking for an answer to this problem like I was, I'd like to spare them the headache of searching any further than necessary for it.

Juidging by [this post](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=126185#p448484) on VideoLAN's forum made by the site administrator (Jean-Baptiste Kempf), this seems to be working as intended.

> Yes, there is *no way to have that mode*. Either it's two windows, or you just have the preview instead of the thumbnail.
>
> (my emphasis)

This is, in my opinion, a silly limitation/feature to have.

EDIT 2019:

It seems to now be possible to achieve what the OP wants. Just drag the top part of the video up and the navigation will get hidden, you'll see a vertical resize icon replacing the pointer icon when you hover over the line between the navigation and the video. This at least works on my version of VLC (Version 3.0.7.1) on Windows 10

I don't know when this was implemented but I'd feel very silly if I didn't try this before originally posting this answer.

Comment: A silly limitation indeed. I already knew that you could manually resize the video but you're still left with "Playlist" at the top, on Linux at least.